# Printer: Is it possible to show print PDF and ePub url link for each node on Views?

Tags: views, files

I have [Printer](https://drupal.org/project/print) module installed on Drupal 7. Let's say I have a view that lists all the articles in table format. I would like to have the PDF and ePub url link next to each article as a field. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add a global text field and under **Rewrite Results** select **output this field as link** and give the path eg. for PDF it should be **printpdf/[nid]**.

similarly you can create one more  field for EPUB using **printepub/[nid]**.

Note **[nid]** is a replacement pattern, you should add nid before these fields and exclude it from display.

Comment: I cant upvote this whole thread enough, haha.

Comment: Ty @wolverine. The link go to page "Page not found". I believe I didn't enable one of the functions. What am i missing? I'm using wkhtmltopdf from https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf and PHPePub from https://github.com/Grandt/PHPePub.

Comment: the url printpdf/[nid] on output this field as link is pointing to /printepub/%5Bnid%5D. am i using the right code?

Comment: You have to add `Content:nid` field before the global fields and exclude it from display if you want. But it should come before the global fields.

Comment: ty @wolverine :)